# Ternary operator add or not where conditions in linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have this query:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(code) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
{
    return this.context.Table.Where(
         x => EF.Functions.Contains(x.Code, $"\"{code}\"") 
         && EF.Functions.Contains(x.Name, $"\"{name}\""));
}
else if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(code) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
{
    return this.context.Table.Where(x => EF.Functions.Contains(x.Name, $"\"{name}\""));
}
else
{
    return this.context.Table.Where(x => EF.Functions.Contains(x.Code, $"\"{code}\""));
}
```

I tried to do it again using the ternary operators then check if the string is not null or empty and if so add the where clause or not
I tried such a thing but obviously expects that after the "?" there is the alternative of ":"

```
return this.context.Table.Where(
    x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(code) 
    ? EF.Functions.Contains(x.Code, $"\"{code}\"") 
    && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(name) 
    ? EF.Functions.Contains(x.Name, $"\"{name}\""));
```

Since unlike the example in my case I have to check 8 different input parameters that if not passed must not be used in the where for the controls, I wanted to avoid filling the code of many if cases and rewriting the query n times for the different combinations, is there a way or should I resign myself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just return `true` for any you don't want to check for like below

```
!string.IsNullOrEmpty(code) ? EF.Functions.Contains(x.Code, $"\"{code}\"") : true;
```

This means if the string is null or empty then it will return true which should provide the behaviour you're expecting.

Comment: Great, it also works well with the simplification suggested by Intellisense

Comment: What did it recommend out of interest?

Comment: (string.IsNullOrEmpty(code) ||  EF.Functions.Contains(x.Code, $"\"{code}\"") ;

Answer (score 1):

Do not use ternary operators for combining query. EF will create non optimal SQL.

Usually such task is done in the following way:

```cs
var query = this.context.Table.AsQueryable();

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(code))
{
   query = query.Where(
         x => EF.Functions.Contains(x.Code, $"\"{code}\""));
}
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
{
    query = query.Where(
         x => EF.Functions.Contains(x.Name, $"\"{name}\""));
}

var result = query.ToList();
```